# JNI return Signal 7 function trying to call to Java from C++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, signals, cocos2d-x

I want to make a call from C++ to Java. I try to call a function which retunt a bool value, without parameters.

This is my C++ Code

```
/**
 * Check if Internet Connection is ONLINE
 */
bool InterfaceJNI::isInternetConnected()
{
    JavaVM* jvm = JniHelper::getJavaVM();
    int status;
    JNIEnv *env;
    jmethodID mid;

    bool isAttached = false;
    // jboolean o bool?
    bool returnValue = false;

    CCLog("Static isInternetConnected");

    // Get Status
    status = jvm->GetEnv((void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);

    if(status < 0)
    {
        //LOGE("callback_handler: failed to get JNI environment, " // "assuming native thread");
        status = jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
        CCLog("isInternetConnected Status 2: %d", status);
        if(status < 0)
        {
            // LOGE("callback_handler: failed to attach " // "current thread");
            return false;
        }
        isAttached = true;
        CCLog("isInternetConnected Status isAttached: %d", isAttached);
    }


    CCLog("isInternetConnected Status: %d", status);

    jclass mClass = env->FindClass("org/example/SocialNetwork/InternetConnection");

    // Get Static bool isInternetConnection()
    mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(mClass, "isInternetConnection", "()Z");
    if (mid == 0)
    {
        CCLog("isInternetConnected FAIL GET METHOD STATIC");
        return false;
    }
    // Call Static bool isInternetConnection()
    returnValue = env->CallStaticBooleanMethod(mClass, mid);
    CCLog("isInternetConnected Done ");

            //-----------------------------------------------------------
    CCLog("Finish");
    if(isAttached)
        jvm->DetachCurrentThread();

    // Change for return value
    return returnValue;
}
```

And my Java code:

```
public class InternetConnection 
{
    /**
     * Check if is working your hello world from C++
     */
    public static void helloWorld()
    {
        Log.v("InternetConnection", "HELLO WORLD");
    }
    /**
     * Check Internet Connection
     * @return true is Online
     */
    public static Boolean isInternetConnection()
    {
        Log.v("InternetConnection", "isInternetConnection Start");

        Context ctx = CCSocialNetwork.getAppContext();
        ConnectivityManager conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo i = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (i == null)
        {
            Log.v("InternetConnection", "isInternetConnection NULL :S");
            return false;
        }

        if (!i.isConnected())
        {
            Log.v("InternetConnection", "isInternetConnection is not connected");
            return false;
        }

        if (!i.isAvailable())
        {
            Log.v("InternetConnection", "isInternetConnection is not available");
            return false;
        }
        Log.v("InternetConnection", "isInternetConnection DONE!");
        return true;
    }
}
```

But I get:

```
 Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x00000000 (code=128)
```

And I have If I can get a return value correctly, I neither would be able to send parameters.

Comment: You are returning a Boolean which is actually an object. Try to return a boolean primitive type instead.

Comment: I have tried to add a boolean vaar in Java but is not that

Comment: The line which fail is "mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(mClass, "isInternetConnection", "()Z");" if I comment that, and the following if, the signal doesnt appear

Comment: The return type must be boolean, not Boolean. I don't know what you mean by 'I have tried to add a boolean var in Java'.

Comment: Well, you are right, changing Boolean for boolean made the trick. But the SIGBUS still appearing

Comment: What line is causing the SIGBUS?

Comment: It seems an error with the getAppContext, I gonna change my code. Please, answer the question and I will check it, you helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a Boolean which is actually an object. Try to return a boolean primitive type instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the FindClass didn't return NULL ? You're not checking for it